# Use gpu on Ubuntu?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I installed CUDA driver, Cudnn and tensorflow-gpu. I can run "nvidia-smi" and "nvcc --version". However, I still cannot use gpu, I don't know why, anyone can tell me?
I use an example from this: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu
But what I get is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfTMV.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use same version cuda-8 as nvidia drivers.
If you use nvidia-384.xx you need to cuda_8.0.xx_384.xx